# IIS Worker Process heavy load

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, iis, cpu

I have a SharePoint 2016 On-Premise two servers farm, one front-end and one for the search. Everything worked fine until few days ago.
The first has a continuous cpu load of 100% where the `IIS Worker Process` takes what it finds, the latter works fine. I noticed that the SQL SharePoint instance takes 20gb and a 50% of CPU. I checked the IIS logs (SharePoint) and I found a lot of 401 errors, but the farm works, slow but it works. Event Viewer has no erros regarding to SharePoint or Authorization.

I tried to restart the SQL Server and the SharePoint front-end, for ~5 minutes the CPU is stable at 30%, then it rises to 90-100%. Restarting just the IIS leads to the same behavior.

ULS does not have any error.

If I stop the `Workflow Manager Backend` service, the CPU load goes to 10%. When I restart it, it returns up to 100%.

How can I find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is it an internet facing deployment?
Are the Workflows working correctly?
401, basically means Unauthorized Access Exception.
Could it be that the `Workflow Manager Backend` service has become misconfigured somehow? Have you tried re-installing the `Workflow Manager Backend` service?
You should, also, check that there are no forgotten services with outdated cached password trying to enter the sharepoint API.

Unfortunately, there's not much more that i could think of in order to help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As I wrote in the question, the farm is working, slow but working. Reinstalling the WF-Manager requires time and is always a fight, it would be the last of my choices. I think the problem relies between SharePoint->SQL servers.

Comment: Then you should run a report of extended events on the sql server.
This will show you want can be happening and which procedures are stalling.
I had faced a similar problem when a client of mine had changed the List View Threshold and was trying to view a document library with thousands of items inside.
Lifting the upper limit of list view threshold made a huge impact on the SQL Server, since the SQL server was searching for 100.000 items on each run, and, overall, it made the whole installment slow.
Switching the list view threshold made the installment operable once again.

Comment: In the `Event Viewer -> Application and Service Logs -> Microsoft-Workflow -> Operational` I've seen there are a lot of entries, ~20 per second. I think this is the problem, there must be one or more WF stuck. I wrote a PowerShell script in order to find them...

Comment: Then you will have to map all of the workflows and search for their triggers.

Comment: I found two workflows which recursively restarted itselfs. Fixed them, cpu load fell.

Comment: Glad to hear that you resolved the issue!
Great Job!